# Plotly chart not corresponding to time (x) data

Tags: python, pandas, charts, plotly

I'm a novice so this code is probably ugly !
I'm trying to chart the content of a simple dataframe (x=time, y=value) with the following code :

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime

import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

starttime = time.time()
now = datetime.datetime.now()
json_url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnLoanOrders&currency=MAID'

json_backup = 'temp.json'
data_store_filename = 'data_store.dat'
df_store = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Time", "Average_Rate"])

df_store = pd.read_json(json_backup)

while True:
    #download the data we want
    j = requests.get(url=json_url)
    content = json.loads(j.content)
    #create a dataframe with that data
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(content['offers'])
    df = df[['rate', 'amount', 'rangeMin', 'rangeMax']]
    #Create a dateframe with the data we intend to store
    df_rate = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Time", "Average_Rate"])
    #converts data type to float so that we can do some math on it
    df[['rate']] = df[['rate']].astype(float)
    df[['amount']] = df[['amount']].astype(float)
    #multiply the rate column by 100 to get the correct rate"
    df['rate'] *= 100
    length = len(df.index)

    average_rate = df['rate'].sum() / length

    df_store = df_store.append({
         "Time": datetime.datetime.now(),
         "Average_Rate": average_rate
          }, ignore_index=True)

    df_store.to_json(json_backup)

    backup = pd.read_json(json_backup)

    trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x = backup.Time,
    y = backup.Average_Rate,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = 'lines'
    )
    py.iplot([trace1])

    time.sleep(30.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 30.0))
```

I'm getting this weird chart that seem to go back in time. I did check my data and time is correct, the chart isn't. Can anyone explain me what is happening and how to avoid it ?

Chart with error : [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ2TG.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? As it stands, the provided code has quite a few undefined variables which makes it impossible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi fuglede, I just edited with the whole code that leads to this strange chart. Thanks for taking the time to read my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `pd.read_json(json_backup)` ends up sorting the index lexicographically, so that 10 comes before 2. Changing that line to `pd.read_json('temp.json').sort_index()` takes care of the issue.

Comment: That worked like a charm ! I should have thought about this when I was just reading my results (not charting them) and saw the index was not in a chronological order. Thanks a lot for the help !